# import huge data before creating insert

Tags: mysql, database, import

I have mysql database. 
Every month periodicly (this operation is for only 1 table and there is no operation to other tables like below)

1. Drop table
2. Insert new records (record count: 400.000.000) (this prosses is about 1 day)
3. Adding index to releated columns (this prosses is about 1 day)

Is there any better way for example first put index then insert records or change database type(currently mysql moreover i can use rdbms, dbms no problem) 
(getting new data from csv files, files count is  around 10000)

Comment: Why are you dropping `table` periodicly? Instead of drop table you can truncate table so you dont have to recreate it.

Comment: Also are any of the 400,000 inserted records actually items which were already there previously, but disappeared when you dropped the table? If so, consider whether you could amend your process so it only inserts new items instead of starting again from the beginning every time.

Comment: @Sadikhasan because i am creating index after all data inserted

Comment: @ADyson all are new items

Comment: "because i am creating index after all data inserted" yes but why? You don't need to re-create an index just because you insert some data.

Comment: @ADyson this is my question do i need to create index before data or not

Comment: Like Sadikhasan said, create the table and the index _once_ when you first create the database. After that, when you do your update you just truncate the table and insert the new data. You don't need to change the schema (in which I include creating tables, indexes etc) just because you insert new data. It's a DML operation not a DDL operation.